# How can i make a flip-flop in laravel-php with boolean values requested from database row?

Tags: php, laravel

So i`m trying to check if my value in row 'Sent' is true or false then i want to create a flip flop which change a html value based on value in that row.

I`ve tried to create a flip flop with 2 variables then i used if statement to compare between database and true/false.

DB migration

```php
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('QrCode', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('codes',255);
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
            $table->boolean("sent")->default(0);
            $table->timestamp("sent_at")->nullable();
            $table->boolean("used")->default(0);
            $table->timestamp("used_at")->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Controller.php

```php
public function update($id)
    {
        $sent = DB::table('qrcode')->where('id', $id)->get(['sent']);
        if ($sent == false) {
            DB::table('qrcode')->where('id', $id)->update(array('sent' => 1, 'sent_at' => now()));
        }
        if ($sent == true){
            DB::table('qrcode')->where('id', $id)->update(array('sent' => 0, 'sent_at' => now()));
        }
        return back();
    }
```

Blade.php (which i think its not necessary but i will put it here)

```html
<td>
 @if($qrcode->used === 1)
    <b><p name="Yes">Yes</p></b>
 @else
   <b><p>No</p></b>
 @endif
</td>
```

Routes and Model are well created...my problem is in controller!

Every time i try to change the value,code return always 1 even if the database row is false.

Comment: simply do `$sent = !$sent;` to flip flop the boolean

Comment: @RiggsFolly nope... it doesn't work! So $sent returns 1 or 0 ... if i use `($sent == 1)`,laravel throw error `Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int` , if i use `($sent == true)` nothing happen .

Comment: $sent is a collection. You could try using first() instead of get() or use $sent->first() to get the first item in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `get` returns a collection. You're trying to check against the value.

Try using the `value` method instead.
From the docs:

> If you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the  value method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results

`$sent = DB::table('qrcode')->where('id', $id)->value('sent');`